# How do I fix an Internet "Super Cache" on my Computer?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet, browser-cache

I have at least one website that I know for certain is "super cached" (or something that causes a similar behavior) on my computer and I have no idea how to clear it out. I will explain the problem first, then what steps I took to try to correct it.

**The Problem:**
One of the development sites I am working on (requires secure login and due to agreement with a client, I cannot provide that to the public) seems to be "frozen". No matter what I do to the files that run on the site, no changes are visible. I can put die/exit statements right in the PHP, completely delete files from the FTP, and the browser (all browsers on my machine actuall: chrome, firefox, IE) always displays the same exact content.

**Troubleshooting:**
I have tried all of the following:

- Modify and/or Remove Files via FTP
- Modify and/or Remove Files via FTP
- Modify and/or Remove Files via SSH
- Verify that the FTP info is 100% correct.
- Cleared the browser's cache via the browser
- Cleared the cache via CCleaner (along with just about everything else it offered).
- Ran Windows Update
- Tried disabling all plugins/extensions for all browsers
- Changed my LAN connection's DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- Manually cleared the %AppData%/Local/Temp directory
- Restarted the computer
- Updated Windows Security Essentials and ran a complete system scan
- Test these changes on a different computer (other computers I tested with all verified any changes I made to the files on the server, but my computer always showed the original content)
- I also tested the site in Ubuntu via VirtualBox on this same machine and Ubuntu recognized the changes, while the main OS (Windows 7) was still stuck
- Went for a walk, got a fresh cup of coffee, ate a bagel, took a deep cleansing breath, and tried it all again.

No matter what I tried, the site is still stuck on my machine, no matter which browser. If I test it in a different OS as a Virtual Machine or on a completely different computer, the site is as I would expect it to be.

I have no idea what options I have left short of completely wiping out Windows 7 and doing a fresh install...

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you describe is not possible. It sounds like your are loading a different version of the website perhaps through your editing software running a virtual server. Check your hosts file. Beyond that nuke the system.  There is no such thing as a "super cache" literally what you describe is not possible so your doing something wrong.

Comment: Hosts file! That's what I forgot to check! there was an entry in the hosts file... one single entry... I forgot I created an entry for it while waiting for the client to make an A Record to point to the subdomian we host for it... If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one. Thank you! man, I feel stupid.

Comment: Also, to further explain the problem, it turns out the IP the hosts file pointed to was for an older copy of the files that were moved for a server upgrade that we put on hold. I have no idea how those files are even still there. crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to Ramhound for pointing out my stupidity, I apparently created an entry in the Hosts file that was redirecting to a different IP. It shouldn't have been a problem since there should have been only one location for the code/site, but I totally forgot we were migrating to a new server and in the process an old copy remained at the old IP. Why it's still there, I have no idea (can't get to cpanel or anything). But removing the hosts file entry fixed it. Thanks Ramhound...